# jmdn. ärgern in a sentence

Tags: grammatical-case, definite-article

I've recently seen the sentence with the verb *ärgern* while learning relative clauses with *wer* and *was*. The sentence is as follows:

> Manche kommen spät zur Arbeit, was der Chef sehr ärgert.

As you can see, here the definite article **der** is used instead of **den**. Is this sentence correct and shouldn't the definite article for *Chef* be in the accusative case in this instance?

Comment: @Closevoter: Wer gerade erst Deutsch lernt und dann auf etwas gesagtes oder geschriebenes stößt, das dem gelernten widerspricht, dem fehlt das Wissen (oder zumindest die Sicherheit) zu entscheiden, was nun fehlerhaft ist: die eigenen Sprachkenntnisse oder das gelesene/gehörte. Daher halte ich ein close-vote wegen off-topic nicht für angebracht.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your hunch is correct.

> *jemanden* ärgern

indicates accusative, which means yes,

> ... was **den** Chef sehr ärgert.

would be correct and *der* Chef is wrong.